# HighChart: Tooltip box thousand seperator

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have create a scatter chart by highchart which need to display some data in a tooltip box.

Most of the numbers contain are big number therefore i'd like to add some number separator in between like the below

[image]

I have research some other posts saying i should do something like `{point.x:.2f}` but since i am getting all my data from a json file, i am not able to add any symbol to the orginal numbers.

The property of my chart's tooltip box looks like below:

```
//*highchart codes
    tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.name}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Fan rate:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Coverage:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Volume:</th><td>{point.z}</td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                followPointer: true
            },
```

Comment: You should be able to use `{point.y:,.0f}` in the tooltip `pointFormat` @ http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Comment: Yes, i have seen those :,.0f :,.1f, but the result do not match what i showed in the picture contain in my question, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I guess its a bug with Highcharts. Perhaps one of the Highcharts team members on stack overflow can help

Comment: Right now you have your thousands separator. This separator is set to ' '. If you need to change this separator, you can do it in lang.thousandsSep parameter. Here you can see an exmaple how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/uxx1ormz/1/

Comment: thanks! may i please reward you ? @GrzegorzBlachliński

Comment: Happy to read that my example met your requirements. I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you have this gap between every thousand is lang.thousandsSep Highcharts parameter. Here you can find information about this parameter:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep

As you can read here, this parameter defaults to ' '.

If you want to change this separator to comma, you can change it inside this parameter.

```
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
  });
```

Here you can find live example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/uxx1ormz/1/

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks, it's so kind :)